# Add new tag to the middle of element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to surround specific words in textContent with HTML tags, this could hypothetically be done by doing `element.textContent = element.textContent.replaceAll("word", "<h1>word<h1>");` but that isn't parsed, and  `element.innerHTML= element.innerHTML.replaceAll("word", "<h1>word<h1>");` doesn't work because there is a risk that the word could be the name of a tag.  Is there any solution besides writing a custom replace function that detects when in a tag?

Comment: you can check beforehand if the word is surrounded with tags via regex. only catch where word is not surrounded by `<` or `>`

Comment: @OctaviaSima That doesn't really work, there is still the risk that there is `<` or `>`  not used to indicate tags, and could be steps removed from the word as it could be a variable of the tag.

Comment: You could probably write a complex regex expression but I feel like at that point you're better off writing a less complex function for parsing.

Comment: @Spectric A browser expression that will need to apply CSS and scripts to specific words in existing text elements.

Comment: Hmm,, if that's the case, could give some example that we can see and their appropriate outputs? also if you can include some edge cases, that would be great.

Comment: @OctaviaSima Well, here's one example: `<p class="questions">What's your favorite class?</p>` and that should become `<p class="questions">What's your favorite <custom-tag>class</custom-tag>?</p>`  But it would become  `<p <custom-tag>class</custom-tag>="questions">What's your favorite <custom-tag>class</custom-tag>?</p>`  Which would break the HTML rendering

Comment: For that specific example, the answer I posted below should work, try if it works on other samples you can think of. If it needs some adjustment, feel free to comment the cases it fails so I can fix the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make sure that the word you're trying to pad is not inside a tag. To do this, you need to check its surrounding characters. As long as they aren't enclosed by `<` and `>` on both sides (or make sure they are enclosed by `<some tag>` on the left and `</?some tag>` on the right like what I did below), they should be the only one to be replaced. Try this regex sample below:

```js
function padTags(content, openTag, word, closeTag) {
  console.log(content)
  const replacement = openTag + word + closeTag;
  const regex = `(?<!<[^<>]*)${word}(?![^<>]*>)`;
  const pattern = new RegExp(regex, 'g');
  return content.replace(pattern, replacement);
}

console.log(padTags(`<p class="questions">What's your favorite class?</p>`, 
                '<custom-tag>', 'class', '</custom-tag>'));
console.log(padTags(`<div><p class="test">class</p></div>`,
                '<custom-tag>', 'class', '</custom-tag>'));
console.log(padTags(`<div> class <p data-customvar="<class>">This is my class </p>class</div>`,
                '<custom-tag>', 'class', '</custom-tag>'));
```

Comment: This is great, thank you, but here's an error case I found `<div><p class="test">class</p></div>`

Comment: Also, since it requires it is surrounded by tags, I think outerHTML should be used instead of innerHTML as there is a chance it contains no tags in innerHTML

Comment: To be honest, I think with a regex approach there will always be edge cases, due to the irregular nature of HTML

Comment: Sorry for the mistake @AidanWelch, forgot to add the other tag on it but it should cover that case too after modifying the regex. Also made it into a function format so you could reuse it more easily and test some cases you could think that this regex will fail.

Comment: Okay, this is near perfect!  And, I thought was perfect, but I have a knack for breaking things and found yet another edge case: `<div> class <p data-customvar="<class>">This is my class </p>class</div>` element data can cause issues with later word matching.  Also, I am just using regex101 for testing

Comment: Hi @AidanWelch, created a room for the both of us discussing possible edge cases, can you check your notifications for chats from me?